# Multiple Input Field Search trouble

Tags: php, mysql, html, mysqli

I have a search function script that searches multiple input fields. The script is searching the database perfectly. The problem is when I use OR operator I have to enter both the fields to search and the results are displayed fine but if I input only 1 field then the search is not functional and the records are displayed. And if I use AND operator I have to enter 1 field and the corresponding results are displayed but when I enter 2 fields the result is NULL. Both AND & OR operators are giving me the transverse results.

I want that when I enter 1 field the matching results should be displayed and when I enter both the fields the results matching both the fields should be displayed.

Here is my index.php search script.

```
//Perform Search from our database
if(isset($_POST['action_type']))
{
    echo '';
    if ($_POST['action_type'] == 'search')
    {
        $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, strip_tags($_POST['searchText']));
        $search_add = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, strip_tags($_POST['searchAddress']));

        $sql = "select contact_id, CONCAT(first_name,' ' , last_name) as contact_name,
                contact_no, residential_address, 
                company, company_address from tblcontact 
                where CONCAT(first_name, ' ', Last_name) like '%$search%' or contact_no like '%$search_add%'  order by contact_id asc";


        $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

        if(!$result)
        {
            echo mysqli_error($link);
            exit();
        }




        //Loop through each row on array and store the data to $contact_list[]
        while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $contact_list[] = array('contact_id' => $rows['contact_id'], 
                                    'contact_name' => $rows['contact_name'],
                                    'contact_no' => $rows['contact_no'],
                                    'residential_address' => $rows['residential_address'],
                                    'company' => $rows['company'],
                                    'company_address' => $rows['company_address']);
        }
        include 'contactlist.php';
        exit();
    }
}
```

Here is my contactlist.php that has the form.

```
<center><div style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
            <form method="POST" action="index.php" >
                <table>
                <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <td><input type="text" id="searchText" name="searchText" style="width: 300px; margin-left: 14px;"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <th>Contact</th>
                <td><input type="text" id="searchAddress" name="searchAddress" style="width: 300px; margin-left: 14px;"/></td>
                </tr>
                <input type="hidden" name="action_type" value="search"/>
                </table><br>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" value="Refresh Search" onClick="window.location.href='index.php'">


            </form>

            </div>
            <div style="max-height: 350px; overflow:auto;">
            <table class="pbtable" border="1">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            ID
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Name
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Contact #
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Res. Address
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Company
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Company Address
                        </th>
                        <th></th><th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead><br><br><br>
                <tbody>
                    <?php foreach($contact_list as $contact) : ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <?php echo $contact["contact_id"]; ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?php echo $contact["contact_name"]; ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?php echo $contact["contact_no"]; ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?php echo $contact["residential_address"]; ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?php echo $contact["company"]; ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?php echo $contact["company_address"]; ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <form method="post" action="index.php">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="ci" 
                                    value="<?php echo $contact["contact_id"]; ?>" />
                                    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="edit" />
                                    <input type="submit" value="Edit" />
                                </form> 
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <form method="POST" action="index.php" 
                                onSubmit="return ConfirmDelete();">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="ci" 
                                    value="<?php echo $contact["contact_id"]; ?>" />
                                    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="delete" />
                                    <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
                                </form>
                            </td>
                        <tr>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>
```

Search should function if 1 field is enterd and also when 2 fields are entered. What is the solution to this problem?

Comment: even i've encountered the same problem recently.. i used `if` conditions to overcome it.. i suggest you too to use if condition..
`if($variable!=""){ //perform one query }elseif($variable2!==""){ //perform another query }`

Comment: show it using my script please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to check if fields are empty:

```
if(!empty($_POST['searchText'])
     $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, strip_tags($_POST['searchText']));
if(!empty($_POST['searchAddress'])
     $search_add = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, strip_tags($_POST['searchAddress']));
```

Then, depending on this you should change the query.

```
if(!empty($_POST['searchText'] && !empty($_POST['searchAddress'])
{
   $sql = "select contact_id, CONCAT(first_name,' ' , last_name) as contact_name,
                contact_no, residential_address, 
                company, company_address from tblcontact 
                where CONCAT(first_name, ' ', Last_name) like '%$search%' or contact_no like '%$search_add%'  order by contact_id asc";
}
else if(empty($_POST['searchText'] && !empty($_POST['searchAddress'])
{
   $sql = "select contact_id, CONCAT(first_name,' ' , last_name) as contact_name,
                contact_no, residential_address, 
                company, company_address from tblcontact 
                where contact_no like '%$search_add%'  order by contact_id asc";
}
else if(!empty($_POST['searchText'] && empty($_POST['searchAddress'])
{
    $sql = "select contact_id, CONCAT(first_name,' ' , last_name) as contact_name,
                contact_no, residential_address, 
                company, company_address from tblcontact 
                where CONCAT(first_name, ' ', Last_name) like '%$search%' order by contact_id asc";
}
```

Adjust your queries according to what you are trying to achieve for the AND case also.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this version of your sql query:

```
$sql = "select contact_id, CONCAT(first_name,' ' , last_name) as contact_name,
                contact_no, residential_address, 
                company, company_address from tblcontact 
                where CONCAT(first_name, ' ', Last_name) like '%"
                .(empty($search) ? "" : ($search."%"))
                ."' AND contact_no like '%"
                .(empty($search_add) ? "" : ($search_add."%"))
                ."'  order by contact_id asc";
```

Comment: this gives a NULL value if both the fields are entered for search

Comment: Thx for reply. Is there a possibility that any of the fields of your table `first_name, Last_name, contact_no` may have a `NULL` value?

Comment: Answer by Aris is WORKING perfectly for me. I just had to use the If and Else statement.

Comment: That's fine - glad you got the help needed :) Thx for reply and all the best in New Year 2015.